# Apply AMI to EC2 reserved instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, deployment

Is there a quick (or any) way to restore an existing EC2 reserved instance back to a base state. ie. Apply an AMI to it and overwrite the existing system?

I'd have thought this would be quite an easy thing to do but I haven't found much about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to "restore" an AMI against an existing EC2 instance.

However, you can very easily create a new EC2 instance from your AMI image and it will be in the state it was in when the AMI was created.  Then you terminate the previous EC2 instance, effectively replacing it with the new one.

Reserved instances are an accounting thing. There's nothing that binds the reserved instance to your existing instance other than the fact that it's running. Your new EC2 instance will automatically be covered by the reserved instance if it's criteria matches the original (AZ, instance type, etc.) and you terminate the original.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for that. It turns out I didn't really understand the way reserved instances worked.

Answer (score 0):

An AMI has references to snapshots. You could use those snapshots to create new volumes. Then you could shut down your existing instance, detach its volumes, attach the new volumes to the instance, and start the instance.